# Книги по железу

Tags: книги, железо

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературу по железу компьютера для углубления своих знаний в этой области. Имею опыт - собрал свой комп. Хочу более детально изучить эту область. Литературу подсказывайте на русском языке.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эндрю Танненбаум Архитектура компьютера (с названием могла незначительно ошибиться). Книжка объемная, но бояться этого не надо. Читала Танненбаума Операционные Системы, все разобрано очень подробно, но без лишнего занудства, читается очень легко (для такой литературы, по-крайней мере)

Comment: Спасибо. Если ещё что-то знаете - пишите!

Answer (score 1):

Сначала полистай в электронном виде: "Популярные лекции об устройстве компьютера" ISBN: 5-94157-313-8

[Книги](http://www.pitbooks.ru/bios/) про BIOS.

Comment: А ещё есть что такое? Просто больше интересно по железу.

Comment: для начала изучи общие принципы. Чтобы лучше вникнуть в железо начни изучать Ассемблер. http://forcoder.ru/assembler/ . Двух зайцев сразу убьёшь и принципы обмена информации в железе освоишь и программирование.

Comment: "принципы обмена информации" - это новый термин?

Comment: Ассемблер не знаю, пишу только на СИ хорошо.

Comment: тык потому и предлагаю, чтоб узнал. Ассемблер поможет лучше вникнуть в суть компьютера.